# Spring aop (custom param in ControllerAdvice & ModelAttribute)

Tags: java, spring, aop, modelattribute

I want to add custom param to ControllerAdvice and ModelAttribute method. Please see code below.

```
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyPage {
   String param();
}


@Controller
public class MyController {
   @RequestMapping...
   @MyPage(param = "a")
   public void myPage() {
     ....
   }
}


@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAdviceController {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addAttributes(Model model, MyPage myPage){
        System.out.println(myPage.param());
    }

}
```

How can I get myPage param work.
I am getting

```
class org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
Exception: Could not instantiate bean class [MyPage]: Specified class is an interface
```

I want to get myPage object with param() value "a"

Comment: What is the end result that are you trying to accomplish with this construct?

Comment: ModelAttribute methods get call for each request handler.

Comment: I want to get myPage object with param() value "a"

Comment: XY problem over here. That's what you want to get. We want to know why.